# Merge if output workbook name already exists

Tags: vba, excel, data-processing

I'm have about 100 `.xls` files under one folder and I have a Macro script to loop through each one to do some data processing. The objective is to split each workbook into three with name `N1`, `N2`, `N3` respectively. So far my `SplitData` Macro worked fine but I have issue with extracted workbooks.

I want to merge newly extracted three workbooks to already existed ones instead of getting alerts like "File N1 already exists." every time. I wonder if there's anyway to achieve this in VBA script? Or any other solutions?

Thanks!

This is my code to loop through folder:

```
Sub OpenFiles()
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xls")

    Do While xFile <> ""
        Call SplitData
    Loop
End Sub
```

This is SplitData Macro:

```
Sub SplitData()
 ' 1. Fill every cells in merged columns for future steps
            Dim cell As Range, joinedCells As Range

            For Each cell In Range("E4:I60")
                If cell.MergeCells Then
                    Set joinedCells = cell.MergeArea
                    cell.MergeCells = False
                    joinedCells.Value = cell.Value
                End If
            Next


            ' 2. Split original sheet into three based on one col value 
            ' loop through selected column to check if has different values
            Const NameCol = "B"
            Const HeaderRow = 3
            Const FirstRow = 4
            Dim SrcSheet As Worksheet
            Dim TrgSheet As Worksheet
            Dim SrcRow As Long
            Dim LastRow As Long
            Dim TrgRow As Long
            Dim Student As String
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Set SrcSheet = ActiveSheet
            LastRow = SrcSheet.Cells(SrcSheet.Rows.Count, NameCol).End(xlUp).Row
            For SrcRow = FirstRow To LastRow
                Student = SrcSheet.Cells(SrcRow, NameCol).Value
                Set TrgSheet = Nothing
                On Error Resume Next
                Set TrgSheet = Worksheets(Student)
                On Error GoTo 0
                If TrgSheet Is Nothing Then
                    Set TrgSheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
                    TrgSheet.Name = Student
                    SrcSheet.Rows(HeaderRow).Copy Destination:=TrgSheet.Rows(HeaderRow)
                End If
            TrgRow = TrgSheet.Cells(TrgSheet.Rows.Count, NameCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            SrcSheet.Rows(SrcRow).Copy Destination:=TrgSheet.Rows(TrgRow)
            Next SrcRow
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True


            ' 3. Extract three new worksheets into three workbooks 
            Dim Pointer As Long

            Set MainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
            Range("E4").Value = MainWorkBook.Sheets.Count

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False   'enhance the performance
            For Pointer = 2 To MainWorkBook.Sheets.Count
                Set NewWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
                MainWorkBook.Sheets(Pointer).Copy After:=NewWorkbook.Sheets(1)
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                NewWorkbook.Sheets(1).Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                With NewWorkbook
                    .SaveAs Filename:="D:\***\Inventory\" & MainWorkBook.Sheets(Pointer).Name & ".xls"
                End With
                NewWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
            Next Pointer

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You've offered no indication on how you could prophesize the expected target workbook name. You aren't opening the workbooks in your loop or passing the filename into SplitData. Perhaps once you've actually opened a file you can determine the target workbook filename(s) and if they exist run MergeData, if not run SplitData.

Comment: @Danni  .... Where is the `SplitData` Macro ? Can you add code from that macro as well ?

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks for you reply. Perhaps I wasn't being clear, the output three workbooks' names are already decided and cannot be changed. The overall process is actually splitting original workbooks based on one column, which has 3 different values `N1 N2 N3`, and then merging each extracted three workbooks into three big ones.

Comment: @MohitBansal Please refer to the updated the question:)

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` may be masking an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have set the filename you want in the path you have in the script, change

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

to

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = false
```

to avoid getting the overwrite warning.

Change it back to true after it's saved to prevent problems elsewhere.

Hope it helps

Comment: Using this demands that you use good error-handling.   If you turn off alerts and then your code fails at some point prior to the alerts being switched back on, you end with Excel in a very bad state.  Read Chip Pearson's excellent article on this - http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm

Comment: @oxwilder Thanks for your reply. But one more question, after the alert is disabled, my first two extracted workbook keeps updating same result from the first workbook that I started extraction while the third one trapped in a loop, adding same result from the starting workbook. I assume there's something wrong with my loop but cannot find it, could you please help me check?

Comment: @Danni I'd be happy to help as may many others here, but you might want to mark this particular question as answered and post a new question stating your next requirement.